# Why is there no standard temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

The standard state for a gas is defined at 1 bar of ideal gas.  Why isn't there a corresponding standard state temperature?

Comment: Note that most data published before 1982 used a standard pressure of one ‘standard atmosphere’, i.e. $p=1\ \mathrm{atm}=101325\ \mathrm{Pa}$.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer**

The standard pressure is not an experimental condition, while the temperature is.

**The long answer**

The main reason the standard state is defined is because it leads to this very useful equation
$$K_p = e^{-\Delta G^\circ/RT}$$
Say you have this reaction: $A \rightleftharpoons B + C$ One way to use this equation is to compute the free energy of 1 mol of $A$, $B$, and $C$ at 1 bar using equations derived for an ideal gas, compute $\Delta G^\circ = G^\circ (B) + G^\circ (C) - G^\circ (A)$, and use that value to predict $K_p$.

If the gasses behave like ideal gasses "in real life" then the measured  $K_p$ will match the $K_p$ computed from $\Delta G^\circ$.  *You can do the measurement at any pressure you want, not just at 1 bar*.* The standard state refers to the pressure you use when computing $\Delta G^\circ$.  The only thing it has to do with the experimental measurement is that it defines the units you should use for your partial pressures when computing $K_p$

$\Delta G^\circ$ does also depend on temperature, but the temperature you chose should be the same as the experimental conditions.  So the temperature is not part of the standard state definition.

**But what about "Standard temperature and pressure (STP)?"**

Standard temperature and pressure (STP) refers to *STP conditions* under which $K_p$ is measured, not the pressure used to compute $\Delta G^\circ$. I know, they couldn't have made it more confusing if they tried when they named these things.

*Of course if you do the measurements at very high pressures or low temperatures, then the assumption that the gasses behave ideally will be less valid and the measured $K_p$ will differ more from the $K_p$ computed from Equation 1.  However, that is a separate issue unrelated to the standard state because the $K_p$ in Equation 1 refers to the $K_p$ you would measure if the gasses behaved ideally at the pressure and temperature used in the experiment.

Comment: if anyone has a different take on this I would very much like to hear it

Comment: See also [Notation for states and processes, significance of the word standard in chemical thermodynamics, and remarks on commonly tabulated forms of thermodynamic functions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac198254061239) and [Standard quantities in chemical thermodynamics. Fugacities, activities and equilibrium constants for pure and mixed phases (IUPAC Recommendations 1994)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac199466030533)

Comment: The standard in STP refers to a legal norm so that sets of data can be compared.  So, both T and P have nothing to do with the thermodynamic standards that you describe and discuss (and most probably understand a lot better than I).

Comment: The various [standard conditions for temperature and pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure) (STP etc.) are explained by this [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: @JanJensen If we had select a different standard pressure e.g. $10$ bar would the equilibrium constant change?

Comment: @adosar yes, if the number of particles change on going from reactant to product

Comment: @JanJensen What determines which standard state we must use? For example if we had a reaction in a open vessel with pressure $10$ bar in order to calculate the equilibrium constant $K$ should we use the standard state with $1$ bar or the one with $10$ bar? What dictates which standard state should be used?

Comment: The standard state has nothing to do with experimental conditions. Sometimes I explain it in terms of units: Let's say one paper report $K_p$ for a reaction as 0.1 bar and another paper reports it as 100 millibar. Clearly using "0.1" and "100" will give different $\Delta G^\circ$ values. So we have all agreed to convert to bar units before computing  $\Delta G^\circ$ (i.e. the standard state is 1 bar).